# Verify only changes in modified files with pre-commit instead verifying whole file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, rubocop

I have applied a pre-commit hook on my repository what I want to do is check for syntax with rubocop but only on changes I am trying to commit.

Currently pre-commit is checking for style and rules with rubocop for all my files which i have modified and not allowing me to commit because of some old code which is not valid as per rubocop.

Is there any way I can change it to check only code which is changed and allow to commit if that code is proper as per rubocop.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can change it to check only code which is changed

The important line is this one:

```
# get the list of files which have been modified
git diff-tree -r --name-only
```

---

#### `hook sample`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Check to see if this is the first commit in the repository or not
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # We compare our changes against the previous commit
    against=HEAD^
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# Redirect output to screen.
exec 1>&2

# Get the list of updated files
files = $(git diff-tree -r --name-only $against);

#
#... Loop over the files and do whatever you want to do
#   

# personal touch :-)
echo "                                         "
echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
echo "                                         "
echo "                                         "
echo "      Your code is bad.!!!               "
echo "      Do not ever commit again           "
echo "                                         "
echo "${default}"

# set the exit code to 0 or 1 based upon your needs
# 0 = good to push
# 1 = exit without pushing.
exit 0;
```

Comment: I think the question assumed that already. But how do you check only the lines you have changed with rubocop?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can change it to check only code which is changed

You need [an easy-to-parse output](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/2.2.3#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelain) of the repository status.

---

**pre-commit**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

CYAN='\033[0;36m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m'
RED='\033[0;31m'

echo "${CYAN}[Ruby Style][Info] Checking ruby style with Rubocop...${NC}\r\n"

git status --porcelain | awk 'match($1, /[^(D|R)]/){print $2}' | grep '\.rb$' | xargs -r rubocop -a \
  && git status --porcelain | awk 'match($1, "R"){print $4}' | grep '\.rb$' | xargs -r rubocop -a

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "\r\n${RED}[Ruby Style][Error] Fix the issues and try to commit again.${NC}\r\n"
  exit 1
else
  echo "\r\n${GREEN}[Ruby Style][Success] Style check successful.${NC}\r\n"
  exit 0
fi
```

The first call to `rubocop` runs against all the changed `.rb` files, excluding deleted and renamed ones.

The second call to `rubocop` runs against all the renamed `.rb` files only.

The `-r` option in `xarg` calls avoid to run `rubocop` on whole repository in the case you have not changed any `.rb` file.

Comment: i guess for pure text only inputs this works, but your regex `/[^(D|R)]/` actually excludes any row where 1st column `$1` contains any one of `"D", "R", "|" (the pipe), "(" left bracket, and ")" right bracket`

Comment: Git documentation says that "The porcelain format is similar to the short format, but is guaranteed not to change in a backwards-incompatible way between Git versions or based on user configuration.".

So, in `$1` you always have these values `[' ', M, A, D, R, C, U]`.

I suppose that my `regex` is correct then, but if you have a better solution, I will be glad to know it :)

Comment: you can truncate `awk 'match($1, /[^(D|R)]/){print $2}' | grep '\.rb$'` to `awk '/^[ \t]*[DR][ \t]+[^ \t]*[.]rb[ \t]/ { print $2 }' ` — only cuz i'm playing it safe and assuming it might be tabs and spaces, and leading edge blanks too. If only single space in between, with no leading edge blanks, then  `awk '$!NF=$(NF=2*/^[DR] [^ ]+[.]rb /)' `

Comment: for ur original intention of `either D or R`, i think you meant `/^(D|R)/` - the square brackets `[` and `]` encapsulating it weren't needed.